# Design pattern for casting rows of Object table

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have an issue with a project. I would like to know if there is a Design Pattern for this case:

I'm retrieving from database a row of objects with different types of data

```
Object[] userInformationsRow = getUserInformationsFromDataBase();
int idColumn = 0;
int nameColumn = 1;
int birthDateColumn = 2;
// 
Integer idUser = (Integer)userInformationsRow[idColumn];
String nameUser = (String)userInformationsRow[nameColumn];
Date birthDateUser = (Date)userInformationsRow[birthDateColumn];
```

There is an another way to develop that kind of code which seems to me verry long to code and difficult to change in the future.

Comment: Use an ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) framework, like Hibernate, preferable through the JPA API.

Comment: [Data Mapper](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can return a class from `getUserInformationsFromDataBase()` this is quite common. If you really need a name for that, then search for *DTO* and *DAO* (or *repository*)

```
UserInfos user = getUserInformationsFromDataBase();
user.getId();
user.getName();
user.getBirthDate();
```

If you don't have control of `getUserInformationsFromDataBase()`, you can hide this mess behind the `UserInfos`, this is a kind of *adapter* :

```
class UserInfos {
    private static final int ID = 0;
    private static final int NAME = 1;

    private final Object[] datas;
    public UserInfos(Object[] datas) {
        this.datas = datas; // This is NOT a good idea, search for array defensive copy 
    }      

    public Integer getId() {
        return (Integer) datas[ID];
    }

    public Integer getName() {
        return (String) datas[NAME];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
int ix = 0;
Integer idUser = (Integer)userInformationsRow[ix++];
String nameUser = (String)userInformationsRow[ix++];
Date birthDateUser = (Date)userInformationsRow[ix++];
```

But consider using a `UserInformation` class with the fields you need and map it to you database in one way or another.